# ''If the B...''

Tags: wordplay

This is an ancient puzzle from an old book that I've never seen anywhere else. Can any of you puzzlers solve it?

> If the B MT put:
> If the B. putting:

Comment: Maybe the [tag:wordplay] tag?

Comment: And I thought this might have to do with the New York City [subways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooklyn%E2%80%93Manhattan_Transit_Corporation).

Comment: You missed the second half: `Never put more : over a - der
You'd be an * it`

Comment: A little google searching suggests that the `*` line is a much more recent innovation, but the puzzle dates back at least to 1864.  Only one of the 1864 hits includes the third line about the `- der`; the rest have only the two lines given here.  But it may also be that the `*` is original but was considered too course for publication in the 19th century.

Comment: Include the title and publication date of the book? Might give us some ideas.

Comment: I saw this published in a lateral thinking puzzle book shaped like a toilet.  Can't find it now, and I don't remember the publisher.

Comment: @MathiasFoster it was published in 1864 in Harper's Monthly, as well as Frank Leslie's Ten Cent Monthly.  Both are found in a Google Books search.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

> If the grate be (great B) empty, put coal on (or maybe in?) (colon);
>  if the grate be full stop putting coal in (on?).

Comment: A game of telephone in the age of the telegram.

Comment: Ah, UK English riddles. Makes more sense than "If the capital be period, putting coal in".

Comment: I think one puts coal *on* a grate, which makes sense, since `:` is a "col**on**."

Comment: @phoog it is pronounced co-lin

Comment: @manshu but it's spelled "colon" and who knows how it was pronounced in the 18th or 19th century when this riddle was probably developed?  Also we can't give too much weight to pronunciation; there's a "p" sound in "empty" that is absent from "MT."  Finally, if you put coal *in* a grate, then it must be small enough to fit into the grate's spaces, and it will fall through.

Comment: @manshu a little google searching will find that this puzzle has been published regularly over the last 150 years, and the answer is always given as "coal on," not "coal in."  (And also that this appears to be an American puzzle, where unstressed vowels are, for the most part, not pronounced as a short "i".)

Comment: @manshu, where is colon pronounced co-lin?

Comment: @Holloway: I pronounce it that way. It's probably a regional thing.

Comment: @Holloway my mistake...i have always pronounced it co-lin, but not from now on. :)

Comment: @phoog It seems unlikely that this riddle would be of American origin, since we never called it a "full stop". It seems that Brits and Yanks both called it a "period" as late as the 20th century, and it's not clear why suddenly the Brits rebelled and had to call it by their own special name. [Source](http://www.bbcamerica.com/shows//blog/2014/09/punctuation-day-brits-call-period-full-stop) I also pronounce the punctuation "colon" more like "coal-in" and the part of the body like "coal-un".

Comment: @ToddWilcox that's what I thought, too (also "great B" seems very British to me).  But all the evidence I've seen points to the USA.  Perhaps the Brits decided to stop calling periods "periods" for the same reason they decided to stop calling soccer "soccer."

Comment: @Holloway English "received pronunciation" has most unstressed syllables with the "i" of "in" rather than "uh" of "bus" or "o" of "on" or the like.  Surely there are many other places where this sound is used.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: From a typographical standpoint, a full stop used to be a period followed by an em quad (a fairly generous amount of space), while periods in other contexts were followed by a normal word space.  Curiously, it has become fashionable to regard the practice of double-spacing after a period as being a consequence of typewriters' limitations, when typists' behavior in that regard is closer to what used to be accepted practice with hand-set type.

Comment: @Deusovi $\diamondsuit$ Apologies if this is an unrelated comment, but how do you write text in grey boxes like the comments above on a phone? I know how to do it using a computer, but not my phone. Is there a way? I ask you because you are one of the moderators of this site. Thanks.