# A message found in aNew England home, centuries old

Tags: riddle

What is the person's name and location, and what is he saying....  message below

Wood

Bob

Mass

If the B open put :

If the B not open don't put :

Comment: Very similar to http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25122/if-the-b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last two lines

> If the grate be open, put coal on.  If the grate be not open don't put coal on.

The reason

> If the "great B" open, put the "colon"

This is a very famous puzzle, and perhaps the most famous version of it is on the wall at Loon Mountain in Lincoln, New Hampshire.  I am not sure who is saying it, but I am going to guess either Bob Underwood, or the innkeeper.

Comment: Where is Bob from?

Comment: @Richard U - Well Bob is obviously from above Mass, so he lives in New Hampshire.

Comment: It's Bob underwood, Andover Mass.